# Unit Testing a Kafka SpringBoot producer

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to create a unit test for my Kafka Producer which is integrated into a file. Here's my Kafka Producer:

```
FileName: MessageProducer.java

public boolean sendMessage(ReceivedMessage message) {
    private String topicName = "output-flow";
    try{
        logger.info("Sending message: {} to topic: {}", message, topicName);
        kafkaProducer.send(topicName, message).get();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Error sending message: {} to topic: {}", message, topicName, e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is what I have done so far for my unit test, obviously, with not success at all:

```
@Mock
private KafkaTemplate<String, ReceivedMessage > kafkaProducer;

private static final String TRANSACTION_TOPIC = "test";

// Function for parameterized values

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getTransactionProvider")
public void sendMessageTest(ReceivedMessage message) {
    MessageProducer mockProducer = new MessageProducer(kafkaProducer);
    when(kafkaProducer.send(TRANSACTION_TOPIC, message)).thenReturn({no idea what to put here});
    when(mockProducer.sendMessage(message)).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(mockProducer.sendMessage(message));
}

// Test for exception
// Fails too
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("getTransactionProvider")
public void sendMessageTest_ThrowsException(ReceivedMessage message) {
    MessageProducer mockProducer = new MessageProducer(kafkaProducer);
    when(kafkaProducer.send(TRANSACTION_TOPIC, message)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> mockProducer.sendMessage(null));
}
```

I get `Exception: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.` for the latter unit test.

Comment: Can you provide the error message of the test? Also, can you provide `getTransactionProvider` method implementation so I can reproduce your test?

Comment: Here's the error for the Test for Exception:  org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

And I tried returning a ListenableFuture for the former unit test but it was giving me zero percent code coverage for the required code.

Comment: You can  write callbacks instead of blocking the main thread execution by calling get in future object

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you should return a new SendResult that would have the methods implemented with the data you expect

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/SendResult.html

And wrap it in a Future

`ListenableFuture<SendResult<K,​V>>`

Alternatively, make `sendMessage` void method (or return a Future itself), and pass in a producer callback parameter that's carried through to send, rather than making it block. Then you can assert the response of the callback

Comment: I used a ListenableFuture for the method, adding the following snippet: ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, ReceivedMessage>> future = mock(ListenableFuture.class);
But it wasn't covering the code that it was meant to, giving me 0% code coverage.

Also can you explain what you mean with the last paragraph?

Comment: You shouldn't need to mock a future. Make the send call return a real instance

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO...

Why does your test case fail?
Because your logic will not throw an error.

Your function will not throw an exception since you catch the exception inside the function as follow and you return boolean value.

```
catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Error sending message: {} to topic: {}", message, topicName, e);
        return false;
    }
```

In that case, you need to test whether the function returns false or not.

As I commented earlier, don't block the main thread by calling the get method in the future object. You can simply implement the future callbacks which can be invoked once you get the result as following

```java
public void sendMessage(ReceivedMessage message) {
    private String topicName = "output-flow";
    try{
        logger.info("Sending message: {} to topic: {}", message, topicName);
          ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future  = kafkaProducer.send(topicName, message);


                future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
    
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
    
                        System.out.println("Message Sent  " + result.getRecordMetadata().timestamp());
                        //your logic for the success scenario    
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
    
                        System.out.println(" sending failed  ");
// your logic if failed
throw new RuntimeException("Kafka Failed");
   
    
                    }
                });
    
    } catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Error sending message: {} to topic: {}", message, topicName, e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the above approach way before posting in on SO but the caveat is that I am using the value provided by Processor in a Producer class which is in turn used in a Consumer class and so it is imperative that I use a return value for my Producer.

Comment: I solved the test failure issue  before my approach is that not answer your question?